# Is it possible that permanently setLocation of button in java

Tags: java

I'm new on Java and I'm trying to make an application that you cant click to button. When mouse on over the button, button location will change randomly. First of all I opened a JForm, I didnt create buttons manually.

I'm working with `mouseEntered` event and these are my codes;

---

```
 int x = 100, y = 100;
Random r1 = new Random();
Random r2 = new Random();
private void jButton1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    jButton1.setLocation(x, y);

}                                    

private void jButton1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    x = r1.nextInt(300);
    y = r2.nextInt(300);
    jButton1.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

---

This is all code in my program. The other part is InitComponents. I've just tried that not using random. 
Here is the problem, the code changes the location. However when i move mouse, button location goes old position(I mean it turns back default position). I think its about Java's layout things. Also I set location of button spesificly like 300,400 but still same problem. When cursor moves, button still turns back old position thats why I think I can say that my problem is not about creating new positions randomly. B
So do you have any ideas ?

Edit---

Thanks for your answering @Mohith P. I opened a class and wrote code which what you gave it to me. It works here the codes ;

```
public class Unclickable extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frm;
    JButton btn;
    JPanel pnl;

    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    Random rnd = new Random();

    public Unclickable() {
        frm = new JFrame();
        btn = new JButton("A-A");
        pnl = new JPanel();

        btn.setLocation(x, y);
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));

        pnl.setSize(400, 400);
        pnl.setLocation(100, 100);
        pnl.add(btn);


        btn.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                x = rnd.nextInt(300);
                y = rnd.nextInt(300);
                btn.setLocation(x, y);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                btn.setLocation(x, y);
            }
        });

        frm.setSize(500, 500);
        frm.add(pnl);
        frm.setVisible(true);


    }
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Unclickable a = new Unclickable();
    }
```

Like a said it works but if use "JFrame Form" it still doesnt work. I still dont understand why. It might be for these codes in InitCompenent

```
  layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(99, 99, 99)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(109, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
```

I tried to set position of labels, there was no problem but button is big problem. Can it be about grouplayout(type of JButton layout) ? and lastly I use panel, i added button inside to panel, still same :/

---

Final Edit

---

I solved the problem. Problem is really funny :) I wrote a code which it gives me buttons location.

```
private void formMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
        jLabel1.setText(jButton1.getLocation().x + "");
        jLabel2.setText(jButton1.getLocation().y + "");
    }
```

Cause of that code I couldn't change position of button. I wrote it that I wanted to button location when It changes. Like I said its funny to me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute Positioning a JButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671607/absolute-positioning-a-jbutton)

Comment: I edit it. Can you look over again ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you try to set the button location based on randomly generating value , so the button position changes randomly.Instead of using random values you just use some fixed values for button position. Also In the above code when the mouse enter event invoked then it randomly generate position vales and change the location.

Try this code,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math.*;

class Tst extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame f1;
    JPanel p1;
    JButton b1;
    int x=100,y=100;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Tst()
    {


        f1=new JFrame("Sample");
        p1=new JPanel();
        b1=new JButton("B1");
        b1.setLocation(x, y);
        b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        p1.setSize(500,500);
        p1.setLocation(100,100);
        p1.add(b1);

        //b1.addActionListener(this);
        b1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() 
        {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
            {
                //jButton1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                x=rand.nextInt(10);
                y=rand.nextInt(10);
                b1.setLocation(x, y);
            }

            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
            {
                //jButton1.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
                b1.setLocation(x, y);
            }
        });

        f1.setSize(500,500);
        f1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        f1.add(p1);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        f1.addWindowListener (new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                f1.setVisible(false);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if(ae.getSource()==b1)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Tst t=new Tst();
    }

}
```

Comment: Isnt it same thing?, button position changes randomly or using random values ? Both same code

Comment: The button position changes due to random values.

Comment: I want exactly it. I want button to positions changes due to random values. It changes but it goes old position. For example I open form and button default position is (100,100). It changed randomly and now new position is (242,352). Now if I move mouse, button position will be (100,100) again. Maybe I understood you wrong. If I did, i am sorry for my English. :(